# Additional information from plotOutput with click in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I try to show and get some information from variogram in shiny. When I use R I use the function identify.

```
v <- variogram(frm,vect,cloud=TRUE)
plot(v$dist,v$gamma)
p <- identify(v$dist,v$gamma)
print(v[p,])
```

Thanks to which I receive information such as:
 `dist    gamma dir.hor dir.ver   id left right`

When I use shiny, I use plotOutput with click, like

UI:

```
plotOutput("plot", click = "plot_click"),
verbatimTextOutput("info"),
```

Server

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
df <- dataaa()
v <- variogram((df$daneWejsciowe)~1,df, cloud=TRUE)
plot(v$dist,v$gamma)})


output$info <- renderText({
df <- dataaa()
paste0("x=", input$plot_click$x, "\ny=", input$plot_click$y ) })
```

In this way I only get x and y. However, I need the most value left right. Do you know, maybe in some way I could get the expected values?

Comment: For the most part, `identify` is finding the distance between the selected point and the rest of the data, and returning the index when that distance is within some tolerance. It should be rather straight forward to use `dist` within your `plot_click`-catching function and the available data, and work it out yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by use `dist` ? How and where?

Comment: Think about it: when you click on the plot, the point of your click is somehow assigned to one of the data rows underneath. It does this by finding the point in the data that has the shortest distance (pythagorean, 2nd normal). R has the function `dist` which can quickly and easily find the distance between sets of points.

Comment: You need the `nearPoints` function (from `shiny`).

Comment: Stéphane Laurent it helped, thank you very much